# Consistent Appearance Between Lock Screen and Log Out Screen in Xubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu, login, themes

I installed Xubuntu 22.04 and applied a Gruvbox theme I downloaded from the internet.

Now, from the application menu, when I press "Lock Screen,"  a login screen comes up that matches my theme in appearance decently; it had the same wallpaper as my desktop, and the colorscheme of the GUI elements also matched. However, when I press "Log Out...", the login screen there looks different; it was the same as the first time I saw it after installing Xubuntu. Is this normal? How can I make it look like the login screen from "Lock Screen"?

Comment: "Is this normal?" — It could be considered normal: when you log out, you leave behind all the personal preferences that you had set up _with your specific user_. When you are logged out, the UI is not aimed at you, it's just a generic piece of UI; it will adapt as soon as it is specified which user's preferences it should adhere to; that's exactly what happens when you log in again. (Also, note the difference between the lock screen (you are logged in, but away from keyboard), and being logged out.)

Answer (score 2):

Install `lightdm-gtk-greeter`, then go to `/etc/lightdm` and edit (or create) `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to contain this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Next, install `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` and run it as root. This is a GUI tool to customize the mentioned greeter. Make sure LightDM can read the files you specify there.

If you want to use some other greeter, then you should read their documentation.